# How to send a signal to a process to cause call to exit() and terminate

Tags: c, gcov, signal-handling

I have a program that only generates the output when it returns normally or when it calls the `exit()` function (I'm trying to use `gcov` on a C program). On a special input my program hangs in an infinite loop so I have to terminate it by sending termination signal. In this situation it won't produce the output I need since it wouldn't call `exit()`.

Is there any way that I can force a running program to call `exit()` and terminate without touching the source code and writing a signal handler?

Comment: Attach to it with a debugger and tell it to call `exit()`.

Comment: There's no signal whose default action is to call `exit()`. Either the signal is ignored, it terminates the process immediately, or it performs special action like suspending the process.

Comment: You could write replacement for a function provided by a share library and used by the program. Load the replacement function using `LD_PRELOAD`, it could check for any condition and call `exit()`, else it would most likely call the original function. More on `LD_PRELOAD` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick This implies that the function replaced is invoked in the logic blocking the program.

Comment: As @Barmar suggested I executed my program within `gdb` and after receiving signal I call `exit()`. That worked pretty well.

Comment: Why not you or @Barmer add this as an answer? So at least this can get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I executed my program within `gdb` and after receiving signal I manually call `exit()` and it worked like charm.